# Selecting Negative frames in timeline

Tags: keyframes, timeline

I am having a weird issue. I can select every frame 0-4 except the negative frame (-1). I am not sure why I can't select it, anyone know why? The red arrow points to the keyframe I can't select? These are keyframed eyelid positions from BlenRig[image]

Comment: Probably all the keyframes were selected and moved to the left, so some of them became located past 0 frame. You can't select anything before frame 0 if not changing setting for that (iirc in user prefs)

Answer (score 8):

Go to File -> User Preferences... -> Editing
and check *"Allow Negative Frames"*

[image: User Preferences -> Allow Negative Frames]

In **Blender 2.92** go to Edit -> Preferences... -> Animation and check *"Allow Negative Frames"*

[image: Edit Preferences -> Allow Negative Frames]