# Automated renderings?

Tags: python, rendering

I have created a set of cards and I need to render 1000 pcs of same card but with just number changing inside the card.

1. In each render number in text object has to change from 100 - 1000 (1 render - 100, 2 render - 101, and so on until 1000)
2. Each render video (I render straight in mpeg4 as animation is only 75 frames long) has to have name in directory folder with relevant number
3. Each render has to start after previous one finishes.

Is there a way to automate these tasks using scripts?

Attached examples below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a sequence of renders and give the user the option to cancel the process through the UI at any given time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/is-it-possible-to-make-a-sequence-of-renders-and-give-the-user-the-option-to-can) also a somewhat similar script based on the first: [Render from -100 frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/224404/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady not really as name in directory of every rendered mp4 video has to be changed too.

Comment: You could try looking into writing a Batch file, which automates the execution of commands on the command line. Because rendering and rendering options can be controlled from the command line, this task should be possible.

Comment: So I figured out a way of what script to use but how can I automate it so that in each line of code number changes to the following number (ascending order).

Example:

bpy.data.objects["129"].hide_render = False
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/Users/.../129"
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
bpy.data.objects["129"].hide_render = True

bpy.data.objects["130"].hide_render = False
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/Users/.../130"
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
bpy.data.objects["130"].hide_render = True